# pandas groupby, then conditional replacement of values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set of 'year', 'location name', 'site', 'lat', 'long'.  For each 'location name', there are ~5 records with unique years.  Each 'location' should have the same 'lat', 'long' value, but occasionally there are typos/wrong values.

I want to groupby 'location_name', and then give pandas some conditions to decide when to replace erroneous lat/long values.  This would involve verifying that the 'site' field is the same for each record but if a given 'location name' has more than 3 records and only one of those records has lat *or* long values that don't match the others, then replace the lat/long with the prevailing values.  Being new to pandas, could someone please help me navigate the functionality of groupby objects to address this question?

Original data:
[image]

Output data:
[image]

With site BR not being fixed b/c the site string is not consistent through all years.

Thanks for any insights!
I am new to pandas and am getting hung up on how to handle the groupby object.

Comment: original data 

date loc_name site lat long

1900 bass AU 12.108 121.08

1901 bass AU 12.108 121.08

1902 bass AU 12.108 121.08

1903 bass AU 2.1 21.1
1900 gene BR 32.404 132.4
1901 gene BR 0 0
1902 gene BA 32.404 132.4
1903 gene BR 32.404 132.4
1900 key SA 20.737 86.704
1901 key SA 20.737 86.704
1902 key SA 20.737 86.704
1903 key SA 2.73 86.704

Comment: output data
date loc_name site lat long
1900 bass AU 12.108 121.08
1901 bass AU 12.108 121.08
1902 bass AU 12.108 121.08
1903 bass AU 12.108 121.08
1900 gene BR 32.404 132.4
1901 gene BR 0 0
1902 gene BA 32.404 132.4
1903 gene BR 32.404 132.4
1900 key SA 20.737 86.704
1901 key SA 20.737 86.704
1902 key SA 20.737 86.704
1903 key SA 20.737 86.704